# What does a "Visit" mean on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, statistics

I was exploring Stack Overflow pages and on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/company) page I found some interesting stats about the site.

- Monthly visitors 51+ million
- Questions 19+ millions
- Avg time between new question 14.3 seconds
- Answers 29+ millions
- Developer got help 45.1+ Billion times

And then this one **5 Visits Average Per User, Each Month**

Is it true? Only 5 visits per user? If I'm understanding it wrongly then what does a "Visit" actually mean on Stack Overflow?

> [image: figures]

Comment: i'd be more interested in what "developer got help" means, as, there's no action on the site that is strictly used to indicate a developer got help other than answer acceptance, and there aren't 45.1 billion answers. If it's just upvotes... people throw upvotes around like candy, often on things that aren't helpful to themselves.

Comment: @KevinB exactly the states are somehow contradictory maybe..

Comment: There are a lot of new users that show up for their one question and never come back, and a lot of old users that haven't visited the site in years. So what is a "user" in "5 visits per user"?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm now that's another question ..

Comment: I'd bet the visits per user per month isn't all that creative, probably something like (Number of visits that month) / (unique users who visited that month).

Comment: @Davy M  even only 5 unique users doesn't make sense... I'm sure that's a lot more than this.

Comment: An interesting part of this figure, is "Per User" - I wonder how this is tracked. I know a lot of professionals that don't have an account. Are the "new users" every time they visit?

Comment: @Stefan nobody knows .

Comment: @RaoHammas: if so, the 5 visits average per user per month question cannot be answered by anybody :-)

Comment: @Stefan but that's on site and someone has written that.

Comment: The site-analytics feature (20K rep required) can show the possible mistake.  The current (covid19 affected) number is 60 million visits **per week**.  So that would make it about 21 visits per cookie per month.  How they count cookies is not that obvious, 7M out of those 60M visits are classified as "new visit".

Comment: @HansPassant wohh. some interesting stats. So basically it's a mistake ? and yeah 21 visits per cookie/user seems legit (if they count it like if a user visits multiple times in a day = 1 visit)

Comment: @HansPassant also as kevin pointed "developer got help" state is also confusing though,.

Comment: You'd have to count at least 2 page views per visit and assume that a developer learned something from the page content.  Plausible.

Comment: @HansPassant ahan. that's good.

Comment: The distribution of visits per user is probably very skewed, the mean is not really helpful in these cases.

Comment: @Trilarion but i think it's not difficult to get it right.

Comment: @RaoHammas Yes, but you need to display more than a single number. Quantiles would be okay for example. 90% visit at least X times per month, ...

Comment: @Trilarion that's safe zone :D

Answer (score 6):

As far I as understand a "visit" is a view of a page other than the home page. So that could be a question, a profile or one of the review or moderation pages available to higher reputation users.

This is certainly the definition used when determining whether someone qualifies for the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges.

If you're not a regular user you might only visit one page a day or every few days as you search for answers to your current problem. Not everyone lives on the site.

Comment: So you believe that 5 visits per user per month is right ? I think(obviously don't have a factual proof) most of the users on SO are regular. If we consider 5 visits right then it means basically that most are not regular users ?

Comment: @Rao - I admit it seems a bit low, but I have no reason to doubt the figures.

Comment: @RaoHammas Surely most users are not regular users. Pareto principle applies to a lot of situations. 20% of users do 80% of the work here. Numbers are somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: @Trilarion so i'm the only one who thinks that most of the users on SO are regular. I mean how can someone program without SO ? :D :)

Comment: @RaoHammas Many programmers I know solve their problems by themselves or with the help of official documentation and have no interest in solving others' problems. They visit SO without registering or logging in. Not sure how many of them are there and it's difficult to quantify.

Comment: @Trilarion while no doubt it's true. But I'm sure such programmers are nowhere(very less) in contrast with all others.

Comment: Most SO users come here thru google search, see answer they need and go with their business.